# Sum of rows on Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the count of rows from my table for a day like Saturday or Sunday.

The code below is not working.

Any idea how to achieve this?

```
SELECT next_day(sysdate-8, 'SUN') from dual;

NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-8,)
-------------------
2014/11/02 21:22:30
```

My attempt:

```
select sum(QTY),GROUP from table where next_day(order_date-8, 'SUN')  group by GROUP;
```

Comment: What is your problem?  You should edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Not a real duplicate, but very related to what I think you are trying to achieve:[Determine if Oracle date is on a weekend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450965/determine-if-oracle-date-is-on-a-weekend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter only Sundays/Saturdays you might need `TO_CHAR()`

```
select sum(QTY),GROUP
from table
where TO_CHAR(order_date,'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') in ('SUN','SAT')
group by GROUP;
```

Comment: Warning: This is no water proof solution, since the result of to_char depends on the NLS settings. There are numerous answers on StackOverflow that provide NLS-agnostic ways to do this.

Comment: thanks tons,its working,


order_date is partition_key as its being used as function now.
this query is going full table scan.

is there any way to use order_date without using to_char function ?

Comment: Better use `TO_CHAR(order_date,'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')` in order to be independent from NLS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `NEXT_DAY()` function as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(qty), group
  FROM table
 WHERE order_date = NEXT_DAY(order_date - 1, 'SAT')
    OR order_date = NEXT_DAY(order_date - 1, 'SUN')
 GROUP BY group
```

That might even avoid the full table scan if you have an index on the `order_date` column. I just tried it on a similar table and using the `TO_CHAR()` method above I got a full table scan, while using this method here I got a full scan of the index on the date column.