# What is wrong with this running total (cumulative column) in Oracle select with a window function?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a query containing `0` or `1` in a column. For demonstration purposes I replaced the `1` with `77` so its more easy to see:

```
select dates.d the_date
, case TO_CHAR(dates.d, 'd') when '7' then 0 when '1' then 0 
    else 77 
  end as is_workday
from (SELECT (to_date('01.01.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') + (LEVEL -1)) 
      AS d FROM DUAL connect by level <=( 
      to_date('31.12.2020','dd.mm.yyyy')-(to_date('01.01.2019','dd.mm.yyyy')))
     ) as dates
```

The result is simply a consecutive date column and a marker if this date is a workday or not. (in real life I do a holiday calculation as well, but that's not the problem):

```
| THE_DATE            | IS_WORKDAY |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |  0         |
| 2019-01-06 00:00:00 |  0         |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-08 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-09 00:00:00 | 77         |
| 2019-01-10 00:00:00 | 77         |
....
```

I want to add a running total over `is_workday`, meaning a cumulative value. I am sure Oracles window functions are made for this.

```
SELECT x.the_date
, x.is_workday
, sum(x.is_workday) over (
    partition by x.the_date          -- define the window
    order by x.the_date asc          -- order inside window
    rows between unbounded preceding -- sum to top
    and current row                  -- sum ending here
  ) as workdays_cumul
FROM (
  select dates.d the_date
  , case TO_CHAR(dates.d, 'd') when '7' then 0 when '1' then 0 
      else 77 
    end as is_workday
  from (SELECT (to_date('01.01.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') + (LEVEL -1)) 
        AS d FROM DUAL connect by level <=( 
        to_date('31.12.2020','dd.mm.yyyy')-(to_date('01.01.2019','dd.mm.yyyy')))
       ) as dates
) x
order by x.the_date
;
```

But I must miss something here, because I do *not* get a running total, but just the value itself.

```
| THE_DATE            | IS_WORKDAY | WORKDAYS_CUMUL |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |  77        |  77            |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |  77        |  77            |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 |  77        |  77            |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00 |  77        |  77            |
| 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |   0        |   0            |
| 2019-01-06 00:00:00 |   0        |   0            |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |  77        |  77            |
| 2019-01-08 00:00:00 |  77        |  77            |
....
```

Obviously it should be:

```
| THE_DATE            | IS_WORKDAY | WORKDAYS_CUMUL |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |  77        |   77           |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |  77        |  154           |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 |  77        |  231           |
...
```

I thought it would wirk like this:

- `sum(x.is_workday)` -- do the sum over the `77`-values
- `partition by x.the_date` -- make windows/sections/parts with one row each (in my case)
- `order by x.the_date asc` -- order those rows by date
- `rows between unbounded preceding` -- sum between very first row...
- `and current row` -- ... and the current row.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Partitioning by the date sums the value for each date (basically group by date). Remove it.

Comment: @JohnHC ohh.... so I have to define "one big window" instead of "a lot of small windows"... I see! replacing with `partition by 1 order by x.the_date asc` seems do do the trick! Thanks, you can make an answer of that. Is `partition by 1` the proper way of "removing it"?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but `TO_CHAR(dates.d, 'd')` is [dependant on your NLS settings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-E118F121-A0E1-4784-A685-D35CE64B4557); you'll get a different answer running this in [sessions saying they are in] the UK and USA for example, as the week starts on different days.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks. I did find a solution with `J` and `MOD 7` and wondered why that is. I wish oracle would mention that easy to spot in their docs at format `D`. -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451090/472245

Comment: Well, I guess I've answered the first part of your comment on that answer *8-) The 'D' entry does say it depends on territory, but it isn't obvious what the effect is. Personally I use the fixed-language Sat/Sun check that question is asking about, but the 'J' calculation is interesting too - just less clear to future code maintainers maybe.

Comment: You can just skip `partition by x.the_date`

Comment: Actually `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` is the default, so you can simply write `SUM(x.is_workday) OVER (ORDER BY x.the_date)`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Hell, now things fall into place for me. I didnt even realize that the quite simple `sum(x) over (y)` syntax even *is* a window function just with defaults. Now it all begins to make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `PARTITION BY` clause of your query as the scope you want for the window is the entire query and not each individual date:

```
SELECT the_date
,      is_workday
,      sum(is_workday) over (
         ORDER BY the_date asc            -- order inside window
         ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding -- sum to top
                  AND current row         -- sum ending here
       ) as workdays_cumul
FROM (
  select d the_date
  ,      CASE
         WHEN d - TRUNC( d, 'IW' ) IN ( 5, 6 )
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1 
         END AS is_workday
  FROM (
    SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' + LEVEL -1 AS d
    FROM   DUAL
    connect by level <= DATE '2020-12-31' - DATE '2019-01-01'
  )
)
order by the_date;
```

You can also use date literals, need to remove the `AS` in the table alias (and don't actually need any table aliases) and can use the difference between date and the start of its ISO week (`d - TRUNC( d, 'IW' )`) as a method of finding Saturday and Sunday that is independent of the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter.

You could also remove the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause as `ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND current row` is the default behaviour. However, if that is the behaviour you require then you may just as well leave it in to demonstrate that that window is your expected result.

**Output**:

```
THE_DATE  | IS_WORKDAY | WORKDAYS_CUMUL
:-------- | ---------: | -------------:
01-JAN-19 |          1 |              1
02-JAN-19 |          1 |              2
03-JAN-19 |          1 |              3
04-JAN-19 |          1 |              4
05-JAN-19 |          0 |              4
06-JAN-19 |          0 |              4
07-JAN-19 |          1 |              5
08-JAN-19 |          1 |              6
09-JAN-19 |          1 |              7
...
24-DEC-20 |          1 |            518
25-DEC-20 |          1 |            519
26-DEC-20 |          0 |            519
27-DEC-20 |          0 |            519
28-DEC-20 |          1 |            520
29-DEC-20 |          1 |            521
30-DEC-20 |          1 |            522
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=acd38185a4888ba108c4b7b848a934e7)*