# extract 2 days of previous data and exclude weekends in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Looking assistance in PL/SQL query.

```
Business Case:
Extract 2 previous business days of data from DATE column excluding weekends.
(Business Days - Monday to Friday)
```

> End users are going to provide only 1 date to extract data.

Example:

1. If Effective_date is on Monday, then need previous 2 working days data of Thursday and Friday.
2. If Effective_date is on Tuesday, then need previous 2 working days data of Friday and Monday.
3. If Effective_date is on Wednesday, then need previous 2 working days data of Monday and Tuesday. and so on.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract 2 days of data from date column excluding weekends in plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426831/extract-2-days-of-data-from-date-column-excluding-weekends-in-plsql)

Comment: You asked this [same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426831/extract-2-days-of-data-from-date-column-excluding-weekends-in-plsql). Why are you reposting it ?